# Firebase dynamic link won't open Appstore when the app is not installed

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have set up the Firebase project and dynamic link.

Tapping Firebase dynamic link while the app is installed: directly open the app, both on iOS and Android.

Tapping Firebase dynamic link while the app is not installed on Android: open the Google Playstore.

But tapping the same Firebase dynamic link while the app is not installed on iOS: show Firebase broken deep link page. It doesn't even open Appstore app.

I have set the Bundle ID, App ID, and Team ID. Is it true that that's the minimum settings needed for Firebase deep link to be able to open iOS Appstore? Or is there any other settings I need to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, turns out on the code inside the app to generate the dynamic link does not have the playstore app id supplied, which explains why it only broken when opening playstore but it's okay when opening appstore.

Answer (score -1):

just add the isi param to your link.

```
https://XXXXX.page.link/?link=https://XXXXX.md/emailverification/91c1970e-cc60-11ec-a7a8-e6704c62b69f.&apn=com.XXXXX.md&ofl=https://qa-XXXXXmd-cloudapp.azure.com?tokenType%3Demailverification%26token%3D91c1970e-cc60-11ec-a7a8-e6704c62b69f.&ibi=com.XXXXX.md&cid=7453129190955138586&_osl=https://XXXXX.page.link/aACsVb4v7hdSpLZz6&isi=11231323
```